# bash change strings with multiple escape characters

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, perl

Hello i try to automate for example change one variable in php file .

```
root /tmp # cat defaults.inc.php|egrep "reply_all_mode"
$config['reply_all_mode'] = 0;
```

I try to first catch this by grep something like that :

```
root /tmp # cat defaults.inc.php|grep '$config['reply_all_mode'] = 0;'
```

but i dont retrive any results...

I try to acomplish change `$config['reply_all_mode'] = 0;` to `$config['reply_all_mode'] = 1 ;` with sed or perl .

how to do this with that kind of characters?

Comment: For this you can use double-quotes, but you will need to escape the dollar signs, eg `sed "s/\$config['reply_all_mode'] = 0;/\$config['reply_all_mode'] = 1 ;/g"`. Double-quotes remove the significance of command separators (eg `& | ;` and space) and of file expansion characters (`? * [ ]`), but retain variable expansion with `$`. You will need to add `<FromFile >ToFile` or use `-i` and a file name for replacement within a file.

Answer (score 0):

All of these characters are special to regular expressions: `$`, `[`, `]`
The all need escaping.

I'd write

```
sed 's/\(\$config\['\''reply_all_mode'\''\] = \)0;/\11;/' file
```

Up to `=` is captured in parentheses, and the `\1` in the substitution part copies that text. Then the `0;` is replaced with `1;`

The messy `'\''` is because the shell's single quoted strings cannot contain single quoted strings. We have to break out of the single quoted string to add a literal single quote. We don't have to use single quotes, but then it's even worse IMO:

```
sed "s/\\(\\\$config\\['reply_all_mode'\\] = \\)0;/\\11;/" file
```

A touch tidier with perl

```
perl -pe 's/\$config\['\'reply_all_mode'\''\] = \K0;/1;/' file
```

Comment: With perl or sed, add `-i` to save the changes in-place.

Comment: Hi , thanks for examples ,
i done similar to grep 

root /tmp # cat defaults.inc.php|grep "\\\$config\\['reply_all_mode'\\] = 0;"
$config['reply_all_mode'] = 0;

and its , working  ;) 

could you you check perl example ?

 
If you got any similar examples , and you can send or publish it here .